# How to use dataset with costume function?

Tags: huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface-datasets, huggingface

I want to call `DatasetDict` `map` function with parameters, and I dont know how to do it.

I have function with the following API:

```
def tokenize_function(tokenizer, examples):
    s1 = examples["premise"]
    s2 = examples["hypothesis"]
    args = (s1, s2)
    return tokenizer(*args, padding="max_length", truncation=True)
```

And when I’m trying to use in this way:

```
   dataset = load_dataset("json", data_files=data_files)
   tokenizer          = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
   tokenized_datasets = dataset.map(tokenize_function, tokenizer, batched=True)
```

I’m getting error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

How can I call `map` function in my example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional parameters, like the tokenizer object, need to be passed by the [fn_kwargs](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v2.4.0/en/package_reference/main_classes#datasets.Dataset.map.fn_kwargs) parameter of [.map](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v2.4.0/en/package_reference/main_classes#datasets.Dataset.map) function:

```py
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import RobertaTokenizer

dataset = load_dataset("anli")
t = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained("roberta-base")

def tokenize_function(examples, tokenizer):
    s1 = examples["premise"]
    s2 = examples["hypothesis"]
    args = (s1, s2)
    return tokenizer(*args, padding="max_length", truncation=True)


tokenized_datasets = dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True, fn_kwargs={"tokenizer":t})
```